# Get All documents in a Collection CosmosDb

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I would like to return all documents in a collection for CosmosDb

My code is as follows

```
 client.CreateDocumentQuery(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(dbName, colName,"id")).ToList();
```

It is not working.  I can find a specific document but not all

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri` creates a Uri for a document specific query.

What you want is all documents in a collection so what you need to create is to create a collection Uri.
You can do that by using `UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseName, CollectionName);`

Just a note on your practice however.
For operations that return a lot of documents you are recommended to use the `.AsDocumentQuery()` method and then do `ExecuteNextAsync` while `query.HasMoreResults`.

You should do it that way because the CosmosDB SDK does make trips over the wire synchronously if you just use `.ToList()` on the `IQueryable` and this will be bad for your application's performance.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.linq.documentqueryable.asdocumentquery?view=azure-dotnet) is an example from MSDN on how you can do that.

```
using (var queryable = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Book>(
    collectionLink,
    new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 10 })
    .Where(b => b.Title == "War and Peace")
    .AsDocumentQuery())
{
    while (queryable.HasMoreResults) 
    {
        foreach(Book b in await queryable.ExecuteNextAsync<Book>())
        {
            // Iterate through books
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your link died & isn't on archive.org. I'm going to [steal some MSDN code from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.linq.documentqueryable.asdocumentquery?view=azure-dotnet) and place it into your answer so that we have a record of it. If the code _doesn't_ represent what you meant, my apologies & please [add a quick sample](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers#comment15235_8259)! Thanks.