# How to correctly get all Items from DocumentDB via webapi

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, azure-cosmosdb

I have the following DocumentDB Repository helper class

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;

namespace TenantManagementWebApi.DataAccess
{
    public static class DocumentDBRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        private static readonly string DatabaseId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["database"];
        private static readonly string CollectionId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["collection"];
        private static DocumentClient client;

        public static async Task<T> GetItemAsync(string id)
        {
            try
            {
                Document document = await client.ReadDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId, id));
                return (T)(dynamic)document;
            }
            catch (DocumentClientException e)
            {
                if (e.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }

        public static async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetItemsAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            IDocumentQuery<T> query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(
                UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId),
                new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = -1 })
                .Where(predicate)
                .AsDocumentQuery();

            List<T> results = new List<T>();
            while (query.HasMoreResults)
            {
                results.AddRange(await query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>());
            }

            return results;
        }

        public static async Task<Document> CreateItemAsync(T item)
        {
            return await client.CreateDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId), item);
        }

        public static async Task<Document> UpdateItemAsync(string id, T item)
        {
            return await client.ReplaceDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId, id), item);
        }

        public static async Task DeleteItemAsync(string id)
        {
            await client.DeleteDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId, id));
        }

        public static void Initialize()
        {
            client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["endpoint"]), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["authKey"]);
            CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync().Wait();
            CreateCollectionIfNotExistsAsync().Wait();
        }

        private static async Task CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                await client.ReadDatabaseAsync(UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri(DatabaseId));
            }
            catch (DocumentClientException e)
            {
                if (e.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                {
                    await client.CreateDatabaseAsync(new Database { Id = DatabaseId });
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }

        private static async Task CreateCollectionIfNotExistsAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                await client.ReadDocumentCollectionAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId));
            }
            catch (DocumentClientException e)
            {
                if (e.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                {
                    await client.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync(
                        UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri(DatabaseId),
                        new DocumentCollection { Id = CollectionId },
                        new RequestOptions { OfferThroughput = 1000 });
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I need to do the webapi crud controller for one entity:

```
 public class Tenant
    {
        public string TenantId { get; set; }
        public string TenantUrl { get; set; }
        public string CertificatePath { get; set; }
        public string CertificatePassword { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
        }
    }
```

I am not sure what to put in the Predicate to get all items which Are Tenant.

```
 public async Task<List<Tenant>> GetTenants()
        {
            return await  DocumentDBRepository<List<Tenant>>.GetItemsAsync(d => d. != null);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your generic `T` object more specific. Limit it to a class that implements an interface of some sort like `ICosmosEntity` and add a `EntityType` property on that interface.

Then make your DTOs implement that interface and set the `EntityType` to the class name. That way you are able to create a dynamic predicate that gets `nameof(T)` and automatically adds it in the `Where` clause of your LINQ query.

If you just wanna get all the items in the collection then in your code the `x => true` predicate will do that but it won't limit it in tenants unless the collection only has tenant objects in it.

Also `ReadDocumentAsync` will only worth that way when your collection has no partition key (which is not really recommended)

It might worth taking a look at [Cosmonaut](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut) as it does exactly what you want and more. It supports the exact same [collection sharing](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut#collection-sharing) logic that you are trying to code.

*Disclaimer, I am the creator of Cosmonaut.*

Comment: can you ellaborate more on the answer (with code), I am confused, I read your github, and I will give it a try later very impressive, but for now I need to solve this,

Comment: I answered the very same question yesterday. It might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51191516/get-all-documents-in-a-collection-cosmosdb

Comment: Install-Package : Could not install package 'Cosmonaut 1.4.7'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6', but the package does not 
contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.